# when to use System.exit(0) and System.exit(2)?

Tags: android

I want to restart the app after the crash. i am using below code to perform that task.

```
 Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(HomeActivity.this, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity,
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

yes it restarting the app but some in other tutorials i found same code for restart of app but with **System.exit(2)** code is below

```
  Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(HomeActivity.this, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity,
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(2);
```

yes in both case app is restarting but i want to know what is the difference between System.exit(0) and System.exit(2). and when to use them particularly?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : **never**.

The reason why you should never use `System.exit(0)` or `System.exit(1)`, nor either value for exit in Android is because it breaks the lifecycle of Activities. Android handles that on it's own, and trying to interfer with it is a very bad idea.

If you really want to kill your app, use [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish%28%29).

You should take a look at [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) to really understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

`exit(0)` generally used to indicate successful termination. `exit(2)` or any other non-zero value indicates unsuccessful termination in general.

For more details, refer to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code of exit implementation:

```
/**
         * Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The
         * argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status
         * code indicates abnormal termination.
         * <p>
         * This method calls the <code>exit</code> method in class
         * <code>Runtime</code>. This method never returns normally.
         * <p>
         * The call <code>System.exit(n)</code> is effectively equivalent to
         * the call:
         * <blockquote><pre>
         * Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)
         * </pre></blockquote>
         *
         * @param      status   exit status.
         * @throws  SecurityException
         *        if a security manager exists and its <code>checkExit</code>
         *        method doesn't allow exit with the specified status.
         * @see        java.lang.Runtime#exit(int)
         */


    public static void exit(int status) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(status);
        }
```